# "The device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected" error when copying a large file from Windows

Tags: file-transfer, windows

I am trying to copy a large file (11 GB) from Windows using File Explorer, i.e. drag'n'drop to an Android device (Nexus 7, Android 4.4, 32 GB), but I get this error:

> Cannot copy item
> The device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected.

There is 26 GB available storage on the device. I can copy a small file with no problems. I was able to copy a 4.9 GB file. The device is connected via USB and USB debugging is enabled.

What is the problem?

Comment: Doesn't directly tell us, but makes it most likely to be MTP. MTP has its limitations in various circumstances, one of them being "timing out" with large amounts of data transferred. I already mentioned `adb push` above, which should be more reliable then. You can find more details in our [adb tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info). Additionally, our [file-transfer tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/file-transfer/info) might be interesting.

Comment: This discussion might be helpful: ***[(SOLVED) This device has either stopped responding or has been disconnected.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2518544)***

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way that works for me is to go to Settings > Developer options > Select USB configuration. First, select Audio source while connecting to the computer, then select Media Transfer Protocol (MTP). The device driver will install automatically.

Comment: Are you suggesting that selecting "Transferring Files" is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You might have an unstable MTP connection - Try swapping USB cable/getting rid of the USB hub if any. Performing a system update of your device will probably help, but it's a long shot.

Comment: I have had issues myself. When I  got a new cable I  realised the previous one was faulty or the connector was not making contact properly.